# embedding cfswitch in cfquery

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

Ok so we're trying to be clever by having database tables with defined fields like:

```
(1) id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded
```

and then extending them for various "objects" like

**Contact table**
    `(2) id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded, sitecode, contactid`

or:

**Article table**
    `(3) id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded, sitecode, articleid, votes`

so you'll notice that (1) becomes is a base, and (2) and (3) extend.

we have a base object that does a database query on those base fields and then we try and magically extend it with the following code:

```
<cfquery name="local.qReturnQuery" datasource="#variables.sDSN#">   
     SELECT id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded, sitecode, contactid
       FROM tbl_#arguments.sPrefix# cb
      WHERE 1
        <cfif arrayLen(arguments.aExtendedParams) gt 0>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(arguments.aExtendedParams)#" index="local.x">
                 <cfscript>
                      local.sParamField = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][1];
                      local.sParamValue = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][2];
                      local.sParamType = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][3];
                      local.bParamIsList = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][4];
                      local.sParamCondition = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][5];            
                      local.bIsPositive = arguments.aExtendedParams[local.x][6];
                </cfscript>
                <cfswitch expression="#local.sParamType#">
                      <cfcase value="integer,boolean" delimiters="true">
                            #local.sParamCondition#
                           <cfif local.bParamIsList>
                                #local.sParamField# <cfif not local.bIsPositive>NOT </cfif>IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.sParamValue#" list="true">)
                           <cfelse>
                                #local.sParamField# <cfif not local.bIsPositive>!</cfif>= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.sParamValue#"> 
                           </cfif>
                      </cfcase>
                      <cfcase value="string">
                            #local.sParamCondition#
                            <cfif local.bParamIsList>
                                  #local.sParamField# <cfif not local.bIsPositive>NOT </cfif>IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#local.sParamValue#" list="true">)
                            <cfelse>
                                  #local.sParamField# <cfif not local.bIsPositive>!</cfif>= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#local.sParamValue#">
                            </cfif>                     
                      </cfcase>
                  </cfswitch>
              </cfloop>
          </cfif>
 </cfquery>
```

Unfortunately my incredible code seems to ignore my `cfswitch` and outputs a query like:

```
SELECT id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded, sitecode, contactid
  FROM tbl_contact_thing cb
 WHERE 1
```

my Array looks like:

```
arguments.aExtendedParams = [{1="contactid",2="44",3="integer",4="false",5="AND",6="true"}];
```

so should look like:

```
SELECT id, name, title, datemodified, dateadded, sitecode, contactid
  FROM tbl_contact_thing cb
 WHERE 1
   AND contactid = 44
```

What might I be doing wrong (in terms of this code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't pore over the code, but I spotted this which is wrong:

```
<cfcase value="integer,boolean" delimiters="true">
```

Your delimiters are not the letters `t`, `r`, `u`, `e`; it's just a comma.

That might not be all the problem, but it's part of the problem.

Docs for [`<cfcase>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fe4.html)

Comment: how did i miss that :(

Comment: You may have missed it because you have so much conditional logic inside a cfquery tag.  It takes away the ability to troubleshoot by looking at your data at various points of the code.  The workaround is to use the logic to build a string variable which you then output inside your query tag.

Comment: Admittedly that is quite true.  Though wouldn't I possibly lose the use of cfqueryparams?

Comment: Using query parameters is a good idea.  So is having programming code that is easy to read and maintain.  If one compromises the other, you've got a decision to make.

Comment: I'd judt write the actual queries you need for your business requirements, rather than write generic catch-all ones. Or if you need that sort of thing (I think it's seldom the best approach at runtime, although it might be easier at coding time; you should optimise for runtime though), then use ORM rather than rolling yer own, I reckon.

Comment: Martin Fowler said;
Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.